# How i can get only the difference between two array objects keeping one property?

Tags: javascript

I have this two array of objects:

```
const groupScreens = [
  {
      "id": "6b7c1891-e98f-4ca5-87db-7d4578268b8f",
      "name": "Cad 1",
      "screen_id": "7b9bb725-2fa8-4416-a664-37395d28da95",
      "group_id": "319588ba-8c5d-474b-aaf2-2ea8fbfed898",
      "allow_read": false,
      "allow_create": true,
      "allow_update": false,
      "allow_delete": false,
      "created_at": "2020-04-07 08:32:58",
      "updated_at": "2020-04-07 08:32:58"
  },
  {
      "id": "7ae7c727-6dd3-43ab-be91-816e34da42ce",
      "name": "Cad 2",
      "screen_id": "b1793127-09f1-4c70-982d-c2cea57709ee",
      "group_id": "319588ba-8c5d-474b-aaf2-2ea8fbfed898",
      "allow_read": true,
      "allow_create": true,
      "allow_update": true,
      "allow_delete": true,
      "created_at": "2020-04-07 08:32:58",
      "updated_at": "2020-04-07 08:32:58"
  },
  {
      "id": "1de0a773-9df8-4e7c-98c0-e12d2f79a3d3",
      "name": "Cad 3",
      "screen_id": "b829677f-c597-48e5-b50d-736b0a1bda00",
      "group_id": "319588ba-8c5d-474b-aaf2-2ea8fbfed898",
      "allow_read": true,
      "allow_create": true,
      "allow_update": false,
      "allow_delete": true,
      "created_at": "2020-04-07 08:32:58",
      "updated_at": "2020-04-07 08:32:58"
  }
]

const changedGroupScreen = [
  {
      "id": "6b7c1891-e98f-4ca5-87db-7d4578268b8f",
      "name": "Cad 1",
      "screen_id": "7b9bb725-2fa8-4416-a664-37395d28da95",
      "group_id": "319588ba-8c5d-474b-aaf2-2ea8fbfed898",
      "allow_read": false,
      "allow_create": true,
      "allow_update": true,
      "allow_delete": true,
      "created_at": "2020-04-07 08:32:58",
      "updated_at": "2020-04-07 08:32:58"
  },
  {
      "id": "7ae7c727-6dd3-43ab-be91-816e34da42ce",
      "name": "Cad 2",
      "screen_id": "b1793127-09f1-4c70-982d-c2cea57709ee",
      "group_id": "319588ba-8c5d-474b-aaf2-2ea8fbfed898",
      "allow_read": true,
      "allow_create": true,
      "allow_update": true,
      "allow_delete": true,
      "created_at": "2020-04-07 08:32:58",
      "updated_at": "2020-04-07 08:32:58"
  },
  {
      "id": "1de0a773-9df8-4e7c-98c0-e12d2f79a3d3",
      "name": "Cad 3",
      "screen_id": "b829677f-c597-48e5-b50d-736b0a1bda00",
      "group_id": "319588ba-8c5d-474b-aaf2-2ea8fbfed898",
      "allow_read": true,
      "allow_create": true,
      "allow_update": false,
      "allow_delete": false,
      "created_at": "2020-04-07 08:32:58",
      "updated_at": "2020-04-07 08:32:58"
  }
]
```

I need to compare this two arrays by the property `screen_id` and return the differences that is in `changedGroupScreen` keeping the property `screen_id`.

I need this result:

```
const result = [{
    "screen_id": "7b9bb725-2fa8-4416-a664-37395d28da95",
    "allow_update": true,
    "allow_delete": true
}, {
    "screen_id": "b829677f-c597-48e5-b50d-736b0a1bda00",
    "allow_delete": false
}]
```

I'm receiving: Cannot set property screen_id of undefined:

```
let result = [{}]
let countResult = 0
let foundedDifference = false
for (let i_group_screens = 0 ; i_group_screens < groupScreens.length; i_group_screens++) {
  foundedDifference = false
  for (let i_changed = 0; i_changed < changedGroupScreen.length; i_changed++) {
    if (groupScreens[i_group_screens].screen_id === changedGroupScreen[i_changed].screen_id) {
      if(groupScreens[i_group_screens].allow_read !== changedGroupScreen[i_changed].allow_read) {
        result[countResult].screen_id = groupScreens[i_group_screens].screen_id
        result[countResult].allow_read = changedGroupScreen[i_changed].allow_read
        foundedDifference = true
      }
      if(groupScreens[i_group_screens].allow_create !== changedGroupScreen[i_changed].allow_create) {
        result[countResult].screen_id = groupScreens[i_group_screens].screen_id
        result[countResult].allow_create = changedGroupScreen[i_changed].allow_create
        foundedDifference = true
      }
      if(groupScreens[i_group_screens].allow_update !== changedGroupScreen[i_changed].allow_update) {
        console.log(countResult)
        result[countResult].screen_id = groupScreens[i_group_screens].screen_id
        result[countResult].allow_update = changedGroupScreen[i_changed].allow_update
        foundedDifference = true
      }
      if(groupScreens[i_group_screens].allow_delete !== changedGroupScreen[i_changed].allow_delete) {
        result[countResult].screen_id = groupScreens[i_group_screens].screen_id
        result[countResult].allow_delete = changedGroupScreen[i_changed].allow_delete
        foundedDifference = true
      }
      if(foundedDifference === true) {
        countResult++
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code you've tried yet? We'll not do the work for you ;)

Comment: @Utkanos i try with the lodash, with differenceBy(): const result = _.differenceBy(groupScreens, changedGroupScreen) but return all the objects, i can't find some similar in the internet to try to, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs something like this, i make this work this way:

```
let result = []
let countResult = 0
let foundedDifference = false

for (let i_group_screens = 0 ; i_group_screens < groupScreens.length; i_group_screens++) {
  foundedDifference = false
  for (let i_changed = 0; i_changed < changedGroupScreen.length; i_changed++) {
    if (groupScreens[i_group_screens].screen_id === changedGroupScreen[i_changed].screen_id) {
      if(groupScreens[i_group_screens].allow_read !== changedGroupScreen[i_changed].allow_read) {
        let obj = {screen_id: groupScreens[i_group_screens.screen_id], allow_read: changedGroupScreen[i_changed].allow_read}
        result.push(obj)
        foundedDifference = true
      }
      if(groupScreens[i_group_screens].allow_create !== changedGroupScreen[i_changed].allow_create) {
        if (foundedDifference === true) {
          result[countResult].allow_create = changedGroupScreen[i_changed].allow_create
        } else {
          let obj = {screen_id: groupScreens[i_group_screens].screen_id, allow_create: changedGroupScreen[i_changed].allow_create}
          result.push(obj)
        }
      }
      if(groupScreens[i_group_screens].allow_update !== changedGroupScreen[i_changed].allow_update) {
        if (foundedDifference === true) {
          result[countResult].allow_update = changedGroupScreen[i_changed].allow_update
        } else {
          let obj = {screen_id: groupScreens[i_group_screens].screen_id, allow_update: changedGroupScreen[i_changed].allow_update}
          result.push(obj)
        }
        foundedDifference = true
      }
      if(groupScreens[i_group_screens].allow_delete !== changedGroupScreen[i_changed].allow_delete) {
        if(foundedDifference === true) {
          result[countResult].allow_delete = changedGroupScreen[i_changed].allow_delete
        }else {
          let obj = {screen_id: groupScreens[i_group_screens].screen_id, allow_delete: changedGroupScreen[i_changed].allow_delete}
          result.push(obj)
        }
        foundedDifference = true
      }
      if(foundedDifference === true) {
        countResult++
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Probably not the best solution (so much code) but is working like i expect. 
(If you have some trick to do this better, feel free to comment)